# Django Celery Redis Auth

Tags: django, authentication, redis, passwords, celery

I'm trying to add Celery to django to schedule tasks. I use Redis backend, and connect via unix socket. Setup was working until I have tried using password auth to redis.conf:

My settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis+socket:///home/username/domain/redis.sock?password=mypasswd'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis+socket:///home/username/domain/redis.sock?password=mypasswd'
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'public_python.settings')
# celery settings for the demo_project
app = Celery('public_python')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Result:

```
[2021-07-19 21:22:14,003: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis+socket:///home/username/domain/redis.sock: Authentication required..
```

I have already tried adding:
`CELERY_REDIS_PASSWORD='mypasswd'`
(any any concievable combination of similar words), with no luck.

Answer (score 5):

The normal format using a network based socket would look like this:

```
redis://:mypasswd@127.0.0.1:6379/0
```

For file based socket, you might want to try:

```
redis+socket://:mypasswd@/home/username/domain/redis.sock?virtual_host=0
```